# "Server Error in '/' Application. Could not find a part of the path" in ASP .NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have made a `ListView` and created a `LinkButton` inside named `lnkDownload` to download an image. My code is working fine on localhost but on server it is showing error.

**Source code**:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListViewSizePrice" OnItemCommand="ListViewSizePrice_ItemCommand" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><%#Eval("Size") %></td>

            <td><asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButtonRawYes" GroupName="RawFile" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="form-control" Checked="true" Text="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Yes" runat="server" Width="70px" />
                <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButtonRawNo" GroupName="RawFile" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="form-control" Checked="false" Text="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;No" runat="server" Width="70px" />
            </td>

            <td><%#Eval("ImageFormat") %></td>
            <td>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenFieldImageUrl" Value='<%# Eval("ImageURL") %>' runat="server" Visible="false" />

           <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" Text = "Download" CommandName="imageDownload" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton></td>

                </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

**CODEBEHIND**

```
protected void ListViewSizePrice_ItemCommand(object  
 sender,ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "imageDownload")
            {
                string ImageUrl = ((HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("HiddenFieldImageUrl")).Value;
                string FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(ImageUrl);
                if (FileExtension == ".rar" || FileExtension == ".RAR")
                {
                    Response.ContentType = "application/rar";
                    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(ImageUrl));
                    string absImageUrl = Server.MapPath("Admin/" + ImageUrl);
                    //absImageUrl.Replace("\\", "\\");
                    Response.TransmitFile(absImageUrl);
                    Response.End();
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
                }
            }

        }
```

**This code works perfectly on localhost. But on server it shows following error**

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Inetpub\vhosts\basiyan.co.in\basiyan.com\Admin\ImagesUploads\Admin 16-05-2017\1\Image 10 X 10\10 X 10.rar'.
```

Comment: Do you have file at \Inetpub\vhosts\basiyan.co.in\basiyan.com\Admin\ImagesUploads\Admin 16-05-2017\1\Image 10 X 10\    Also what is the imageURL value in hidden field ?

Comment: Have you validated that the string is correct, so there are no hidden characters in the ImageUrl?
Do you want to download the image to the client? Or do you want to upload the Image from the client?
It looks like you want to download the Image, I am just asking to be sure.

Where do you get the ImageURL from? It could be a mix up of  client side pathing, being sent to server side MapPath. That wouldn't work naturally.

What debugging methods have you already used?

Comment: @Ankesh Kumar: yes , file exists on server at given url. Second,

Comment: @Ankesh Kumar: yes , file exists on server at given url. Second, ImageURL contains path of file from "ImageUploads" upto file present on server.i.e. in this case its value is  "ImagesUploads\Admin 16-05-2017\1\Image 10 X 10\10 X 10.rar"

Comment: @MortenBork : I have validated the string and its correct. I want to download the image to client. ImageUrl gets value from database where it stores the path from "ImageUploads" folder upto the file being downloaded.

Comment: string absImageUrl = Server.MapPath("Admin/" + ImageUrl); at this line you are mapping in Admin folder and then the said path, Do you think is it correct ?

Comment: @Piyush

Since it works on localhost, have you validated that your server application has permission to read the files in that directory?

Have you validated that your response headers have permissions to transmit the file types away from the server? That might explain why it works on local-host, but when you try to access it from a client, it stops working. However, from your error message that doesn't seem right.

If it's not one of those two, I need more information to help further. Those are my best guesses.

Answer (score 0):

Check File path

place the required file in Publish

try to get file path dynamically instead of storing it in a hidden field